# Framework plugin architecture solution

Tags: architecture

I want to ask for an idea for creating plugins/components in a web framework(cms) like wordpress.

I'm asking for conceptual idea not code.

So imagine I have core components like pages, users, contents, settings, etc.

Next i want to add functionalities via plugins that could be installed separately (like in wordpress).

My questions is how these plugins will interact with the core structures.

For example if i have Seo component that adds some admin panel fields for managing meta tags for each page.

If Seo plugin adds fields to "Pages" admin panel, and other plugin adds another fields how can i make sure that the fields are in some order for exampe.

On the other hand if I the plugins add new panel sections this could be harder to manage - I should create page then go to another section and manage the seo tags from there - more time to create pages.

For me if Seo is really plugin it should be disabled/uninstall /enabled separately from other plugins.

Also if some other plugin depends on Seo plugin - is the Seo plugin really a plugin.

Because if a uninstall it - the other code that depends on Seo plugin will break.

Can you suggest good architecture that creates modular architecture via plugins/components.

My problem is that it's hard to separate different plugins without interacting with each other.

If I have Authenticate plugin (handling login/logout logic) the code will be all over the place and I cannot just simple "disable" it and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will try to share my thoughts in general way, then I will give more specific answers.

First of all, all plugins should share the same design as code- eg. you must define your own interfaces and lib for building the plugins. Plugins itself should be loosely coupled and no dependency between plugins and core components. Only core components (Pages) should be able to be extended - they are first level plugins - you can define rules to load service definitions from certain plugins directory.

Integration between the plugins can be achieved with Command design pattern - in that way you can chain multiple plugins and make them work together.

Integration with core components can be done with dependency injection and null object pattern - a way to swap services definitions with empty implementation  - in that way you can disable your login / logout.

Plugins should be able to uninstalled as well - in that way you need to remove all plugin files. Based on that requirement its not possible to merge core components and plugins - core components should know where there need to looking for services files (container definitions) load them and show what ever is there. If you remove the plugin files - core components should continue to exists.

As you mention wordpress - if you are gonna using MySQL you can create relation tables for all plugins data that extends core components. When you remove the plugin - remove related tables.

In the frontend you can use combination between MVP and MVI. In that way based on events you switch off login components - so your login, logout, register link will be not visible on multiple places - you can have it on bottom or on top of the page- no if statements.

Overall the goal is to get rid of the if statements, loosely coupled code and clean way to integrate plugins with core components and chain plugins.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation, can you give some basic example how to get rid of if statements MVP MVI (pseude code will be helpful). Another hard thing is for example if my plugin add field to core panel "pages" how to be customizable from the plugin itself because if the form is changed from other plugin, my plugin will know about existing of other plugin. Thanks

Comment: nice, well recently I watch this presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dS9gho9Rxn4 and here is the source code: https://github.com/julianomoraes/componentizationArch- I know its android but you can get the concepts and apply similar approach with react, vue.js to your cases. Plugin shouldn't add field to core "pages" it should create new db table related to pages table next pages should has code to boot plugin container files. Basically using DI container (special for admin) you can show plugin data. Pages will load only one xml file from plugins/containers/myPlugin.xml and it will go

Comment: Thanks, i will watch it, but the main idea is that I want to "modify" existing functionality, not to create another isolated "panel". That way it's easier, but I wonder how to do it with changing/adding fields and etc which happens in real world (this apply not only for admin panel but for website, too) For example your plugin want to add "remember me" checkbox in the login form, want to add sharing buttons for post pages (but the title will be get from the specific post with connection between them)

Comment: remember me should be part for auth plugin with option to turn on / off? I see how you want to mix different plugin together - again I think this can be done with such approach. However the chalange - auth plugin, remember me plugin, forgot password plugin - to be able to customise position of remember me vs forgot password link - should get on top with additional plugin that is repossibile only for that configure via xml for example. From there you can put predefined values, create custom themes. what do you think?

Comment: in your case you will have something like dynamic layout and auth plugin should know how to wire remember me and password forgot plugin and then create additional theme to style them. With above approache - create DI with container definitions and command pattern I believe you can achieve that. First step by step as proof of concepts for that use case - auth plugin + remember me and password forgot plugin. I think is best use case.

Comment: Thanks, that could work but imagine this is backend plugin - if I depend on another plugin and do nothing if it is uninstalled/disabled I can get unexpected behaviour of the system - imaging removing Authenticate plugin - the login functionality will not work. Maybe that desired behaviour but if i add xml managing another plugins it will get complicated very quickly

Comment: Well you must keep things loosely coupled. If you disable enable plugin your system should handle that gracefully. For example - you will miss only the functionality not error 500. During the plugin disable you can remove also part from xml. XML was only a shoot the dark - better not to have such things. Its a complicated solution for sure. You need to clear all the cases first and to me you can star with that auth, remember me, password forgotten scenario.

Comment: You need to get plugin scaffold kind of framework when you will have all the desired behaviour. One more idea - during the registration to get extra step that is getting from additional plugin. This also valid case for chain of command pattern.